# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS After deploying SmartStore on azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc

facing this issue for days. I have tried many approaches in order to solve it, however, none of them works.

The error I`ve been facing:

[The issue I have been facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRpwS.png)

The admin module of SmartStore has been working without any issues, the only problem is with the web module of SmartStore. P.S: I have no CDN profile on azure.

What I have tried:

I have tried clearing caches, worked on several different browsers and devices in order to test it. Nothing seems to solve the issue.

Link to the web: https://smartstoreweb20210927175106.azurewebsites.net/

However, if we type any random route after it like lets say:
https://smartstoreweb20210927175106.azurewebsites.net/a

It gives 404 error like it should.
Also, if we try to access admin module:
https://smartstoreweb20210927175106.azurewebsites.net/admin

It works perfectly, and also the registration and other functionalities of the app itself. Any insight would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Find TSL/SSL Settings of your Azure Subscriptions and Turn off the HTTPS only. Hopefully, It will work for you.

The screenshot is attached for your reference.

[image: Reference]